# $("#MyForm").submit(function () { Does not work in IE8 but FireFox 8?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MyForm").submit(function () {
        alert("Hello");
        return true;
    });
});
```

Hi, I have a very simple code above, when I submit the form in IE8 nothing happens, but it works fine in FireFox 8.

I am using jQuery 1.5.1. So is it a problem from old version of jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before in IE8 and IE7. Workaround:

```
$("#MyForm").submit(function () {
    alert("Hello");
    return true;
});

// change input type to whatever submits the form
$("#MyForm input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: That'll cause a double submission of the form. Perhaps you should include a `preventDefault` in the `click` handler.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, I tried, it does not seem to cause double submission.

Comment: @hardywang: The original version without `preventDefault` did, but probably not in the broswsers that were giving you the issue.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, I tried the original version in both IE8 and FF8, I don't see double submission. But I have updated my code to new version anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @hardywang: Strange. I tested in Chrome, and it did. Anyway, sounds like you've got it working. :)

Comment: @RightSaidFred, with new code to add 'preventDefault' it stops double submission in FF8, but in IE8 I see the double submission. If I switch to old version of code somehow -- neither calls 'preventDefault' nor calls '$(this).closest("form").submit();' then I don't get double submission in IE/FF. Weird...